# Docker - Alpine Deno + Node, Issue with Node libstdc++ version information (not found)

Tags: node.js, linux, docker

Creating a Docker network, one of the containers needs to run both Deno & Node. I've got the below Dockerfile.

```
# Alpine Image
FROM example:testing

# Exposing Port 80 for the Docker Network
EXPOSE 80

# Installing git & openssh
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \ 
    alpine-sdk \
    git \
    openssh \
    curl \
    bash
    
# NVM Environment Variables
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 16.4.2

# Installing NVM & Node
RUN curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash

RUN echo "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install $NODE_VERSION && \
    nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION && \
    nvm use default" | bash

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN node -v

# Creating SSH Home Directory
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
COPY ./.dev/.docker/ssh /root/.ssh

# Setting Working Directory to Deno
WORKDIR /app/deno

# Installing Dependencies
COPY ./.dep ./.dep
RUN deno cache ./.dep/mod.ts

# Installing any additional, uncaught dependencies
COPY . .
RUN deno cache ./lib/cli.ts

# Setting the docker env
COPY ./.dev/.docker/.env ./.env

# Executes the CLI Startup
CMD ["sh", "./cli"]
```

Which successfully creates the image. However upon running the container and testing `node -v` out, I get the below output

```
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
v16.4.2
```

Which isn't exactly an encouraging output. What's happening here, why & what's the fix?

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is `example:testing`? can you show the Dockerfile for that? is it alpine?

Comment: It is indeed alpine, apologies

Comment: afaik nvm doesn't work on alpine properly. Even nvm's base image is ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah just learnt this a few minutes ago, it's more to do with how node is compiled it seems. Switched to using Ubuntu :)